# How to convert AES 128 CBC encryption from Oracle to php using openssl?

Tags: php, oracle, encryption, openssl

I have the following Oracle code and the matching PHP but both are returning different results.
**Oracle Code:**

```
DECLARE

   raw_key          RAW(200);
   encryption_type  NUMBER;
   encrypted_result VARCHAR2(4000);
   decrypted_result VARCHAR2(4000);
   v_key            VARCHAR2(4000) := 'This!@#@#SSkkLeoKeyWAA';

BEGIN

   raw_key := utl_i18n.string_to_raw(v_key, 'UTF8'); 
   encryption_type  := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes128 + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc + dbms_crypto.pad_pkcs5;
   encrypted_result := dbms_crypto.encrypt(utl_i18n.string_to_raw('200601RR00001', 'UTF8'), encryption_type, raw_key);
   decrypted_result := dbms_crypto.decrypt(encrypted_result, encryption_type, raw_key);
   dbms_output.put_line(encrypted_result);
```

**PHP translation**
Based on the PHP doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php I came up with this

```
$string = strtoupper(implode(unpack("H*", "200601RR00001")));
$key = strtoupper(implode(unpack("H*", "This!@#@#SSkkLeoKeyWAA")));
$cipher="AES-128-CBC";

$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$cipherATS = openssl_encrypt($string , $cipher, $key, 0 , $iv);

echo $cipherATS."\n";
```

Comment: I know nothing about PHP or Oracle but it doesn't look the same to me.  Things like: Use of "strtoupper" and IV in PHP but not in the Oracle would mean the two are never going to work.  In PHP just try simple strings and not use the IV and see if that works.

Comment: e.g. $cipherATS = openssl_encrypt("200601RR00001" , "AES-128-CBC", "This!@#@#SSkkLeoKeyWAA");